# mariadb-secure-installation not working after source installation

Tags: mariadb-10.4

I builded MariaDB 10.4 using GitHub source on CentOS 8.
(https://mariadb.com/kb/en/get-build-and-test-latest-mariadb-the-lazy-way/)

But mariadb-secure-installation is not working.

There is no error when running it. But nothing works. For example, changing the root password or deleting an anonymous account does not work.

What should I check?

thank you.

Comment: I figured out why.
https://serverfault.com/a/897341

Comment: In order for your work to be useful to the community, please add an answer to your question with your new insights.
A link is a good start, but a full explanation will increase the value of this question.

Comment: @user2182857 i got it. i added an answer at this question. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why.

https://serverfault.com/a/897341

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/

> In MariaDB 10.4.3 and later, the unix_socket authentication plugin is installed by default, so if you do not want it to be available by default on those versions, then you will need to disable it.

there are two solutions.

1. disable unix_socket authentication

```
# /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf
[mariadb]
...
unix_socket=OFF
# or
disable_unix_socket
...
```

2. set client to use TCP protocol

```
# /etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf
[client]
protocol=tcp
```

or using '-h' option

```
# mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```